# PHP GD and True Type Font

Tags: php, gd, truetype

I have a weird issue with TTF and PHP GD 2.x.

I have a size 45px TTF at top position 100. The top of the text is perfect align with a line (in the image).

BUT if I change the size of the font, the text is no longer align with the line.

At size 20px I need to subtract 5 to the top value of the text and if the font is size 300px I need to add 56 to the top value to get the perfect alignment.

And the worse if I change font (another TTF) it's the same but with different number.

Did I miss something. Why I need to change the top value of the text depending of the size of it and why the number I have for one font is not the same as another one?????

And if all that is normal. How can I get a formula to always get the text align on the line.

Here some number....

```
Font 1 . size 20 = top 95, size 45 = top 100, size 300 = top 156.
Font 2 . size 20 = top 91, size 193 = top 100, size 300 = top 105.
```

I'm not so good in math....sad

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using Imagick, which lets you query the [font's metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Font_metrics). You probably need either the font's x-height, or cap height value, which you can't get from GD.

Once you've got those values, then you can properly calculate the vertical offset you need to line everything up.

Comment: WOW, the change fix my issue and Image Magick it's lot easier.